# Installing nginx 1.9 on CentOS7 VPS

Tags: nginx, centos, yum

Apologies for the noob question. I'm trying to upgrade nginx on my DigitalOcean CentOS7 droplet from 1.8.0 to 1.9.x.

This is my /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo file:

```
# nginx.repo

[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

($basearch is x86_64)

Whenever I run `sudo yum install nginx`, I get:

`Package 1:nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't use [the right repo](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, want to throw that into an answer? I'll accept it!

Answer (score 6):

Damn it. I needed to point to the mainline repo, instead of the stable one.

I updated nginx.repo to the following:

```
# nginx.repo

[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I now have nginx 1.9.5 :)

Comment: I originally had 1.6.3 installed by following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos-7 and when I added nginx.repo as you suggested here I only get 1.8.1 -- how can I get the most current version?